# SharePoint Online integrated with CRM Online says, "We're sorry, we can't sync because you've run out of space."

Tags: dynamics-crm, sharepoint-online

I was trying to sync my document on SharePoint Online where I got an error saying, "we're sorry, we can't sync because you've run out of space."

I believe this is independent of the CRM storage space we get (which is still under 8% filled for my CRM organization)

How do I find how much and what is consumed?
What do i need to do to increase space?

Kindly Help.
Thanks.

Comment: You can do this at the site collection - https://portal.microsoftonline.com/ I believe. You're on Enterprise right?

Comment: There is also a tool from Quest Software - Site Administrator Reports.
Here http://sar.ondemand.quest.com

Comment: And could I be able to add more space on specific GBs I want?
I'll take a look though.

Comment: Enterprise is up to 5TB, Small Business is only 35GB. How much data do you think you are storing?
I'll put this into an answer to stop the comments becoming a chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find how much space is being consumed in a couple of ways.
If you are an Enterprise customer you will have 5TB in total and can use the Microsoft portal [link to the portal](https://portal.microsoftonline.com)
Small businesses have 35GB.

There should be a Storage Metrics function. Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Storage Metrics which you need to start running, but a while later will have the data you need about where space is taken up.

There is also a third party utility by Quest Software (others are available but this is free) and it is called Site Administrator Reports.
[link to the tool here](http://sar.ondemand.quest.com)

Of course you'll need Admin privileges to access the portal and run the tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot VictorySaber :)